# Submit array from Fluid-Template to Controller with f:form viewhelper

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I am currently writing an Extbase Extension with a backend module.  I have assigned an array to the template of my backend module. Now I am trying to submit that array back to my crontroller action "pageGenerator" with inputs of the form in the template.
Here is the code from my controller and template:

Controller:

```
public function listAction()
{
    $array = [
        '1' => '',
        '2' => '',
        '3' => ''
    ];
    $this->view->assign('array', $array);
    $this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename('EXT:bm_test/Resources/Private/Templates/template.html');

}
public function pageGeneratorAction(array $array=null){}
```

Fluid-Template:

```
 <div align="center">
  <f:form method="post" controller="DomainModel" action="pageGenerator" 
     name="array" object="{array}" >
    <input type="text" name="array[1]">
    <input type="text" name="array[2]">
    <input type="text" name="array[3]"> 
    <f:form.submit value="Submit" />
</f:form>
 </div>
```

The problem is that the array is null no matter what I type into the textfields.When i remove the "=null" from the pageGenerator action i get the following Error:

```
Too few arguments to function Bmt\BmTest\Controller\DomainModelController::pageGeneratorAction(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

So it seems like that the array isn't submitted.
Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to insert the assign variable after setTemplatePathAndFilename ?
Becouse in typo3 if the template haven't the same name of the Action you need first inizialize them and after return the view with assigned variable 
example

```
$this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename('EXT:bm_test/Resources/Private/Templates/template.html');
$this->view->assign('array', $array);
return $this->view->render();
```

Comment: I just tried that but sadly it didn't work. I have also narrowed down the problem by confirming that the array actually gets received by the template. I can acces it from the template.